# Robolectric 4 AndroidX NoClassDefFoundError MonitoringInstrumentation with IntelliJ 2018.3.4

Tags: intellij-idea, robolectric

**Problem**

- after switching to androidX
- with a multi-module Android library
- using IntelliJ 2018.3.4 #IC-183.5429.30
- using Robolectric 4.1 with android gradle plugin 3.3.1
- when executing Robolectric tests, I receive:

  ```
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: androidx/test/runner/MonitoringInstrumentation
  ```

**No duplicate question:**

*I read the other topics which pop up when using google or stackoverflow search but they are about a more specific error which is worked-around via adding specific dependencies. In my case I was not able to determine which dependency to add.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I read that no workaround should be required with Android Studio 3.3 and Robolectric 4.0.*

- Use Android Studio 3.3.1+ with Robolectric 4.0+

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

I add dependencies to  *androidx.test:core*
for the build type under test.

In my case it was *debug* so in the build.gradle I add

> debugImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.2.0'